# On a sum related to alternating sign matrices

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to prove that
$$A_{n,k} = \binom{n+k-2}{k-1}\frac{(2n-k-1)!}{(n-k)!}\prod_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{(3j+1)!}{(n+j)!}$$
implies
$$A_n = \sum_{k=1}^nA_{n,k}=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(3j+1)!}{(n+j)!}.$$
In other words, I want to show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k-2}{k-1}\frac{(2n-k-1)!}{(n-k)!}=\frac{(3n-2)!}{(2n-1)!}.$$
My first thought was that this would be easy, but now I'm not so sure. We can write $\frac{(2n-k-1)!}{(n-k)!}$ as $\binom{2n-k-1}{n-1}(n-1)!$ but I don't know what good that will do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The third line makes sense, but the first two don't. You're saying that some number $A_{n,k}$ being defined as it is implies that some number $A_n$ is defined as it is, but there are no logical implications involved. So your "implies" word in the second line is a little weird. Are those quantities $A_{n,k}$ and $A_n$ defined somewhere in your work or anywhere else?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: The sum of the numbers $A_{n,k}$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ is equal to $A_n$. I should have spelled it out above.

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense. Let me think about this identity for a while now. :)

Comment: Quick idea : what goes wrong if you try to see the left-hand side with a combinatorial interpretation and you dissect that counting with some respect to $k$? I'm asking because I wonder how it could go wrong.

Comment: This "conjecture" was proved.  Shouldn't it be called the "Alternating Sign Matrix Theorem" now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's, indeed, rewrite $\frac{(2n-k-1)!}{(n-k)!}$ as $\binom{2n-k-1}{n-1}(n-1)!$ and divide both sides by $(n-1)!$. Now we want to prove that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k-2}{k-1}\binom{2n-k-1}{n-1}=\binom{3n-2}{2n-1}
$$
or, equivalently, that
$$
\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1+s}{n-1}\binom{2n-2-s}{n-1}=\binom{3n-2}{2n-1}
$$
— which is just a (Chu-)Vandermonde identity ($\sum\binom{a+s}c\binom{b-s}d=\binom{a+b+1}{c+d+1}$ — see e.g. identity (5.26) in «Concrete Mathematics»).